# Validation function with return value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a common validation function

```
function connect_and_update_destination() {
        var flag = true;
        // Validate IP
        if (!validate_ip_address()) {
            alert(protect.lang.enter_valid_ip);
            return;
        }

        if ($('#pjm_alias').val() === '') {
            $('#pjm_alias').focus();
            alert(protect.lang.enter_alias);
            return;
        }

        if ($('#pjm_auth_name').val() === '') {
            $('#pjm_auth_name').focus();
            alert(protect.lang.enter_auth_name);
            return;
        }

        if ($('#pjm_auth_password').val() === '') {
            $('#pjm_auth_password').focus();
            alert(protect.lang.enter_auth_pwd);
            return;
        }
        var ip = $('#pjm_ip1').val()+'.'+$('#pjm_ip2').val()+'.'+$('#pjm_ip3').val()+'.'+$('#pjm_ip4').val();
        return establish_connection(ip, $('#pjm_alias').val(), $('#pjm_auth_name').val(), $('#pjm_auth_password').val());
    }
```

After successful validation it always return **establish_connection()**, My problem is that am calling this **connect_and_update_destination()** like this,

```
function first_call(){
  connect_and_update_destination();
}
function second_call(){
  connect_and_update_destination();
}
```

When first call i need to return after successful validation **establish_connection()**, But when ever i called its using second function [second_call()] it should not return **establish_connection()** insted of return **establish_connection()** i need to only return . But how can i do this, Means i dont want to enter establish_connection() when ever i call using **second_call()**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if u r calling on button then show ur button code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something as simple as passing a variable.

```
function connect_and_update_destination(establishConnection) {

 ...

 if(!establishConnection)
   return;

 return establish_connection(ip, $('#pjm_alias').val(), $('#pjm_auth_name').val(), $('#pjm_auth_password').val());
}

function first_call(){
  connect_and_update_destination(true);
}
function second_call(){
  connect_and_update_destination(false);
}
```

For a more generic solution, you could pass a callback:

```
function connect_and_update_destination(callback) {

    ...

    if(typeof callback === 'function') {
       return callback(ip);
    }

    return;
}

function first_call() {
    var result = connect_and_update_destination(function(ip) {
       return establish_connection(ip, $('#pjm_alias').val(), $('#pjm_auth_name').val(), $('#pjm_auth_password').val());
    });
}

function second_call() {
    connect_and_update_destination();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a parameter to the `connect_and_update_destination` function:

```
function connect_and_update_destination(establishConnection) {
    var flag = true;
    // Validate IP
    if (!validate_ip_address()) {
        alert(protect.lang.enter_valid_ip);
        return;
    }

    if ($('#pjm_alias').val() === '') {
        $('#pjm_alias').focus();
        alert(protect.lang.enter_alias);
        return;
    }

    if ($('#pjm_auth_name').val() === '') {
        $('#pjm_auth_name').focus();
        alert(protect.lang.enter_auth_name);
        return;
    }

    if ($('#pjm_auth_password').val() === '') {
        $('#pjm_auth_password').focus();
        alert(protect.lang.enter_auth_pwd);
        return;
    }

    if (!establishConnection) {
        return;
    }

    var ip = $('#pjm_ip1').val()+'.'+$('#pjm_ip2').val()+'.'+$('#pjm_ip3').val()+'.'+$('#pjm_ip4').val();
    return establish_connection(ip, $('#pjm_alias').val(), $('#pjm_auth_name').val(), $('#pjm_auth_password').val());
}
```

and then:

```
function first_call() {
    connect_and_update_destination(true);
}
function second_call() {
    connect_and_update_destination(false);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not solved.Because in second call its not checking all the validation. when ever the second call initiate its just return from the validation function, its not validate ip address etc.

Comment: Where are you validating this `ip` address? Inside the `establish_connection` function? If so you will have to pass the `establishConnection` parameter to this function so that it could validate the `ip` but not do whatever you don't want it to do.